# Custom Control Overridden Text Property Default Value

Tags: c#, properties, custom-controls

I have created a user control that has a textbox inside of it. I have overridden the Text property of the base control like the following:

```
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Description("Test1"), Category("Test")]
    public new string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            textBox1.Text= value;
        }
    }
```

Now, I am having this issue where any instances i create of the control in a form, the Text always have a value of the controlname + number (of instance). I want to know why is this happening, and how to remove this default value? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Initial hunch is that it is calling `ToString()` on the object. Override `ToString()` to return your desired value.

Comment: I totally forgot about ToString(). That is probably why I get the value. Thanks, Aaron. Though, overriding it has no effect. One thing I forgot to mention is that the [Browsable(true)] is the attribute causing that behavior. By removing it, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `DefaultValue` does not set the default value.  The attribute is for describing what the default value is.  You have to set the default value yourself, and then use the attribute to describe it.

So in your example, textbox1.Text must be populated with the control id.  On your UserControl, in `OnInit` or wherever appropriate, you should call

```
this.Text = "";
```

Comment: I have tried setting the Text in many events and did not work, s_hewitt. I can make a hack to remove the value, but it is ugly.

Comment: You'll probably have to post more code then.  It's not clear to me how your controls are setup and how that is leading to the issue.

Comment: The problem is mostly in [Browsable(true)], as I have mentioned in the other comment. Create a control with a textbox on it and try the code above, and you will see what I mean. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I can't reproduce any issues.  If you can isolate this in a new project with just the Usercontrol, please post that code.

Answer (score 2):

```
[DefaultValue("")]
public override string Text
{
    get { return base.Text; }
    set
    {
        if (this.DesignMode && (Environment.StackTrace.Contains("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.InitializeNewComponent")))
            return;
        base.Text = value; 
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, although the code may work, please don't forget to add an explanation.